# how to call a method whenever tapping outside of listview in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have created simple demo to explain what i am looking for...

i have called a method for deselecting listview item in all three IconButtons...

I dont think its a good way of coding..

i want to know ..is there any way to call this method whenever tapped outside of listview...like lostfocus.

```
Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            child: Row(
              children: [
                IconButton(
                    onPressed: onPressMethod,
                    icon: Icon(Icons.edit)),
                IconButton(
                    onPressed: onPressMethod,
                    icon: Icon(Icons.delete)),
                IconButton(
                    onPressed: onPressMethod,
                    icon: Icon(Icons.refresh)),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: 10,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return ListTile(
                        onTap: () {
                          setState(() {
                            selectedIndex = index;
                          });
                        },
                        title: selectedIndex == index
                            ? Text(
                          'selected',
                        )
                            : Text('$index'));
                  }),),
        ],
      )
```

```
void onPressMethod()
  {

    setState(() {
      selectedIndex=null;
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Gesture Detector

```
GestureDetector(
                behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
                child: Container(
              ---your widget----
                ),
                onTap: () {
                onPressMethod();
                },
              ),
```

> A widget that detects gestures. Attempts to recognize gestures that
> correspond to its non-null callbacks. If this widget has a child, it
> defers to that child for its sizing behavior. If it does not have a
> child, it grows to fit the parent instead.